# Non-random missing values in 2SLS regression

Tags: regression, missing-data, instrumental-variables

I have historical cross-sectional data on the presence of newspapers in 15 Indian states in the 19th century. This is my independent variable X. My dependent variable Y is values measured among ~4000 respondents. Each person is an observation and is assigned his/her home state.

I wan't to instrument the independent newspaper variable X with press regulations Z, for which I have data up until 1835. All 15 states had not been annexed by the British at this point. Therefor, my instrument is only relevant for the equivelant of 6 states. Assigning the other 9 states NA-values for press regulation ommits them from the first-stage in the 2SLS regression, and thus ommits all respondents who are assigned to those 9 states.

How can I correct for this very biased sample of states relevant to my instrument?

1. Separate variables for pre 1835 and post 1835 newspapers, where I only instrument pre 1835?
2. Replace my instrument's NA with 0 for states that were not annexed by 1835, and add a dummy variable to the first-stage with 1 for annexed and 0 for not annexed? Does that make sense?
3. Is Heckman's selection model useful for this?

Thanks!